# Non-vectorized Gradient Descent

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have a bug in the following code, which is returning inf, inf for the Thetas.

```
def gradient_descent(x, y, t0, t1, alpha, num_iters):
for i in range(num_iters):
  t0_sum = 0
  t1_sum = 0
  for i in range(m_num): # I have a feeling that the following partial derivatives are wrong
    t0_sum += ((t1*x[i])+t0 - y[i])
    t1_sum += (((t1*x[i])+t0 - y[i])*(x[i]))
  t0 = t0 - ( alpha/m_num * (t0_sum) )
  t1 = t1 - ( alpha/m_num * (t1_sum) )
return t0, t1
```

Thanks

Comment: The variables x and y are lists of integers, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. The only thing: you used the same variable for both loops.

Just change `i` by `j` in the first loop and it will work.

For validation you can use the `normal equation`, which provides the best solution for the problem without using any loops.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def gradient_descent(x, y, t0, t1, alpha, num_iters):

    m_num = len(x);

    for j in range(num_iters):
        t0_sum = 0
        t1_sum = 0

        for i in range(m_num):
            t0_sum += ((t1*x[i])+t0 - y[i])
            t1_sum += (((t1*x[i])+t0 - y[i])*(x[i]))

        t0 = t0 - ( alpha/m_num * (t0_sum) )
        t1 = t1 - ( alpha/m_num * (t1_sum) )

    return t0, t1


def norm_equation(x, y):
    m = len(x);
    x = np.asarray([x]).transpose()
    y = np.asarray([y]).transpose()

    x = np.hstack((np.ones((m, 1)), x))

    t = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(x.transpose(), x)), x.transpose()), y)
    return t


x = [6, 5, 8, 7, 5, 8, 7, 8, 6, 5, 5, 14]
y = [17, 9, 13, 11, 6, 11, 4, 12, 6, 3, 3, 15]

t0 = 0
t1 = 0
alpha = 0.008
num_iters = 10000

t0, t1 = gradient_descent(x, y, t0, t1, alpha, num_iters)
print("Gradient descent:")
print("t0 = " + str(t0) + "; t1 = " + str(t1))

print

t = norm_equation(x, y)
print("Normal equation")
print("t0 = " + str(t.item(0)) + "; t1 = " + str(t.item(1)))
```

Result:

```
Gradient descent:
t0 = 1.56634355366; t1 = 1.08575561307

Normal equation
t0 = 1.56666666667; t1 = 1.08571428571
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was such a simple mistake